# Convergence of sequences: What dowe do in case of complex numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I want to check if the following sequences converge or not.

1. \begin{equation*}a_n=\frac{n^4-n^3-\frac{1}{n}}{\left (2n^2+2\right )^2}=\frac{n^4-n^3-\frac{1}{n}}{4n^4+8n^2+4}=\frac{n^4\cdot \left (1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^5}\right )}{n^4\cdot \left (4+\frac{8}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^4}\right )}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^5}}{4+\frac{8}{n^2}+\frac{4}{n^4}}\rightarrow \frac{1-0-0}{4+0+0}=\frac{1}{4}\end{equation*} So it converges to $\frac{1}{4}$.
2. $ \ $ \begin{align*}a_n&=\frac{n(2n-1)(n+2)+\sqrt{n}-\left [\sqrt{2n}(n+1)\right ]^2}{4n^2+1}=\frac{n(2n^2+4n-n-2)+\sqrt{n}-[2n(n+1)^2]}{4n^2+1}\\ & =\frac{2n^3+3n^2-2n+\sqrt{n}-2n(n^2+2n+1)}{4n^2+1}=\frac{2n^3+3n^2-2n+\sqrt{n}-2n^3-4n^2-2n}{4n^2+1}\\ & =\frac{-n^2-4n+\sqrt{n}}{4n^2+1} =\frac{n^2\cdot \left (-1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^3}\right )}{n^2\cdot \left (4+\frac{1}{n^2}\right )}=\frac{-1-\frac{4}{n}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}^3}}{4+\frac{1}{n^2}} \rightarrow\frac{-1-0+0}{4+0}=-\frac{1}{4} \end{align*} So it converges to $-\frac{1}{4}$.
3. \begin{equation*}a_n=\frac{\displaystyle{\sum_{j=0}^n n^j}}{n^{n+1}}=\frac{\frac{1-n^{n+1}}{1-n}}{n^{n+1}}=\frac{1-n^{n+1}}{(1-n)n^{n+1}}=\frac{1-n^{n+1}}{n^{n+1}-n^{n+2}}=\frac{n^{n+2}\cdot \left (\frac{1}{n^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{n}\right )}{n^{n+2}\cdot \left (\frac{1}{n}-1\right )}=\frac{\frac{1}{n^{n+2}}-\frac{1}{n}}{\frac{1}{n}-1} \rightarrow \frac{0-0}{0-1}=0\end{equation*} So it converges to $0$.
4. \begin{equation*}a_n=(-1)^n\cdot \frac{2n^2+1}{(n+1)(\sqrt{2n}-1)(\sqrt{2n}+1)}\end{equation*}

Let $b_n:=\frac{2n^2+1}{(n+1)(\sqrt{2n}-1)(\sqrt{2n}+1)}$.

We have that
\begin{align*}b_n&=\frac{2n^2+1}{(n+1)(\sqrt{2n}-1)(\sqrt{2n}+1)}=\frac{2n^2+1}{(n+1)(2n-1)}=\frac{2n^2+1}{2n^2-n+2n-1}=\frac{2n^2+1}{2n^2+n-1}=\frac{n^2\cdot \left (2+\frac{1}{n^2}\right )}{n^2\cdot \left (2+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}\right )}\\ & =\frac{2+\frac{1}{n^2}}{2+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}\rightarrow \frac{2+0}{2+0-0}=1\neq 0 \end{align*} So the sequence $a_n$ doesn't converge.

5. \begin{equation*}a_n=\left (\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^n\end{equation*}
   I tried to check the absolute value: \begin{equation*}|a_n|=\left |\left (\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^n\right |=\left |\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right |^n=\left (\frac{|1+i|}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^n=\left (\frac{\sqrt{1^2+1^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^n=\left (\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}\right )^n=\left (1\right )^n=1\end{equation*} but this doesn't help? What can we do in this case?

Answer (score 1):

The final sequence diverges. Note that $a_{n+1}=\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)a_n$ and that therefore, if it converges to some $l\in\Bbb C$, then\begin{align}l&=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)a_n\\&=\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\right)l\end{align}and that therefore $l=0$. But you cannot possibly have $l=0$, since $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):|a_n|=1$.

Comment: I haven't really understood the last part, why can it not be $l=0$ ?

Comment: Because, for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $|a_n|=1$, which means the distance from $a_n$ to $0$ is $1$. But if we had $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, then the distance from $a_n$ to $0$ would be smaller than $1$ if $n$ was large enough.

Answer (score 0):

In 5. we have $a^2=i$ so $a_{8n}=(i^4)^n=1^n=1$ and $a_{8n+1}=a_1a_{8n}=a_1$ so the sequence does not converge.

$\{a_n:1\le n\le 8\}$ is the set of the 8 complex solutions of $z^8-1=0.$

Your work on the other 4 problems is all correct and clearly presented.